# Custom Print Preview in Java Script

Tags: javascript, html

How can i develop custom print preview dialog as like browser print preview using Java script?
I am developing a book reader which need to customize the print preview dialog (to count pages, auto pagination and font size changing).

is there any JS library to do this? Please let me know is there any way to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: And what did google say? stackoverflow isn't a search engine.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to use much Javascript for that task, CSS and its *media queries* will do the job.

You can define a sheet like

```
@media print {
  body {
      width: 100%;
      color: red;
  }

  #someElement {
      display: none;
  }
}
```

That way, you can just clone your actual markup for a new *window* or *popup* and apply those stylesheet definitions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This will work with browser's default preview dialog. I need own custom preview dialog as like browser's print preview dialog.